# Accessing custom jbake confing properties in asciidoc

Tags: jbake

After some time I spent staring at the jbake code, I figured out that if I declare my own property in `jbake.properties` :

```
...
foo=bar
...
```

I can reuse that in files that go through a template engine by referencing  it as `${config.foo}`. I'd like to have this substitution working also on the content lvl, i.e. for files written in asciidoc, living inside the content directory.

Is there any non-trivial way to achieve it? How can I make the templating engine to proccess the result of asciidoc parses engine, or make it running it before the asciidoctor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer myself.
To use the property substitution in asciidoc files, add following to the `jbake.properties`:

```
...
asciidoctor.attributes.export=true
foo=world
...
```

and reference the variable in `aFile.adoc` this way:

```
Hello {foo}!
```